# Large simplicial complex is naturally equivalent to Singular complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to work through Problem 9.15(i) of Rotman's Algebraic topology text.

## Problem

[image]

## Relevant Results

[image]

[image]

## Claim.

$F$ is naturally chain equivalent to $S$.

## Partial Proof.

By Corollary 9.13 (parts (i) and (ii)), it suffices to show that there exists models $\mathcal M$ such that $F_k$ and $S_k$ are free with bases $\mathcal M$, and every model is totally $F$-acyclic and $S$-acyclic.

By examples 9.4 and 9.5, we know that $F$ and $S$ are free with models $\mathcal{M} = \{ \Delta^p \}$.

Every model is totally $S$-acyclic because $\Delta^p$ is contractible, so $\tilde{H_n}(S_* \Delta^p) = 0$ for all $n \ge 0$.

Similarly, $\tilde{H_n}(C_* \Delta^p) = 0$, where $C$ is the simplicial complex functor.

So it remains to show that $\tilde{H_n}(C_* \Delta^p) \cong \tilde{H_n}(F_* \Delta^p)$. I'm not sure how to do this!

Define the natural chain map $j_k : C_k \hookrightarrow F_k$ by $ [<p_0, \ldots, p_k>] \mapsto <p_0, \ldots, p_k>$ with $p_0 < p_1 < \ldots < p_k$ (we define $j_k$ on a basis of $C_k$ and extend by linearity). This map is clearly injective.

Perhaps this induces an isomorphism in homology? I can't prove it.

## Questions

1. If $C$ and $F$ are isomorphic in homology, please provide a proof of this.
2. If not, please help me close the gap in my proof or otherwise any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: Isn’t this (a version of) the simplicial homology <—> singular homology correspondence? You can probably find proofs to your liking of this fact online

Comment: @FShrike: as I stated in the post, it would suffice to show that $F_* \cong C_*$ in homology -- so that's what I'm trying to prove.